# custom keyboard in react-native

Tags: react-native, keyboard, custom-keyboard

I am new to react-native. I need to create numeric keyboard for iPad. basically I want to create custom keyboard. Can any one provide me link or any example explained in detail. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try `https://github.com/themodernjavascript/react-native-custom-keyboard-kit`

Comment: @Auticcat Yes, I had checked, but it is having some issue.